# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Estou obtendo esse exception no c# quando tento ler dados do SQL. Estou com duvidas se este erro é problema com meu SQL ou no C#.

Meu codigo SQL que faz a conversão é esse:

```
`$
(SELECT ORDEM 
                FROM TABELA UP (NOLOCK) 
                    WHERE UP.LAYOUT = r.LAYOUT
                    AND TIPOUSUARIO =CASE
                                        WHEN TIPOUSUARIO = 2 THEN 'A'
                                        WHEN TIPOUSUARIO = 3 THEN 'P'
                                        END
                    AND CODUSUARIO = @CODUSUARIO)
            , r.IDSQL+100) AS ORDER

$
```

E o código no c# que faz a leitura é este:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfig.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = @"sp_vm_getUserItems";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@...", context.UserId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERTYPE", (int)context.UserType);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@...", context.AffiliateId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@..", context.CorporateId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@...", context.CourseId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@..", context.SchoolYearId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@...", context.LevelEducationId);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                            result.Add(new ReportItem() { Layout = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]), Tipo = Convert.ToString(reader[1]), Ordem = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]) });
                    }

$
```

Observação: Os pontinhos são simplesmente pra evitar divulgação do código, mas nos lugares deles tenho os campos que verificam dados do contexto do usuário.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso? não consigo receber os dados da tabela em função desta exception!

Comment: Por favor, não escreva em upper case.

Comment: desculpa, é pq eu tava mexendo no sql....vou alterar

Comment: TIPOUSUARIO  é varchar?  e os CODUSUARIO = @CODUSUARIO são do mesmo tipo? o select é só esse?

Comment: TIPOUSUARIO é varchar, cod usuario é é varchar , o select tem outras partes, mas o problema eh na conversão mesmo. queria fazer um CASE WHEN 'A' Then 2 WhEN 'P' then 3  mas n funcinou tb n

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro é que você está convertendo algum valor string para int e isso não é possível.
Você acha que receberia algo como "01", faça a consulta acima direto no SQL e veja o resultado q ela está retornando.

Ex:

```
var numero = Convert.ToInt32(""teste"");// esse é seu problema esta vindo uma string que não é possível converter.
```

Onde está ocorrendo?
Quase impossível de saber com o pedaço de código que postou, provavelmente na criação de algum parâmetro int.
ou no código

```
result.Add(new ReportItem() { Layout = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]), Tipo = Convert.ToString(reader[1]), Ordem = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]) });
```

tente fazer algo assim

**Solução 01** - Breakpoint e analisar os valores

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var valorZero = reader[0]; //add breackpoint e verifique cada valor
    var valorUm = reader[1];
    var valorDois = reader[2];


    result.Add(new ReportItem() { 
         Layout = Convert.ToInt32(valorZero) , 
         Tipo = valorUm.ToString(), 
        Ordem = Convert.ToInt32(valorDois)
     });
}
```

**Solução 02** - tryparse

Você também pode tentar um `int.TryPare`

```
var valorZero = 0;
int.TryParse(reader[0].ToString(), valorZero);
```

*OBS: esses nomes de variáveis não segue uma boa pratica, utilize um nome que represente algo em seu sistema e não valorZero, etc*

Comment: Esquecid de mencionar a exception ocorre quando ele executa while(reader.Read()), com isso nem entra nesse Result.add.

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não esta clara, o seu código está incompleto, não da para entender o que você tem na sua proc sp_vm_getUserItems e onde você esta usando o seu primeiro código que parece ser na aplicação, mas ....

Esse é um erro [comum do banco de dados](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/8b137d46-6782-4f44-89d0-9b770842de1e/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-648701-to-data-type-int?forum=aspnetpt), quando você tenta passar um valor do tipo `varchar` para um campo do tipo `int`.

Provavelmente o erro esta em uma das duas variáveis.

```
TIPOUSUARIO ou CODUSUARIO = @CODUSUARIO
```

Caso `TIPOUSUARIO` seja um `int` você não pode passar os valores do seu case `'A' ou 'P'` ou se um dos dois `CODUSUARIO = @CODUSUARIO` sejam de tipos divergentes causaria o mesmo erro.